# Can someone tell what encoding this is?

Tags: encoding

I've been working on a small project and came across some information that has some sort of encoding (I assume).

7C-FC-1B-C9-97-1B-A9-EB-2E-45-2A-73-CE-E3-17-F9

01-3E-6A-50-09-ED-1C-A1-80-A0-27-B9-0C-D3-C4-9D

89-4C-B3-52-4A-B8-93-CB-95-4F-E2-9A-0C-59-7C-FD

Does anyone know what sort of encoding this is? I looked into UTF-8 since this came from a SQL file. No luck there.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is written in hexadecimal. Not encoded

Comment: I tried hexadecimal. I have another line and I know what the line is supposed to be in text.